# Extract arguments from functions & use them as logical sentences

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was exploring `THREE.js` & was trying different geometries in it. So as it has a whole lot of geometries writing every single one manually is too boring.

I would have to write these lines for a simple cube to be displayed:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 20, 20, 20 );
var box = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, material );
box.position.set(-10, -10, 0);
scene.add( box );
```

To add another one say a cone i would have to just copy paste the above lines & then replace `Box` with `Cone` & you know that's my computer's work (not mine). Humans are not made for copying :)

So i wanted a general `class` after which i can say something like:

```
var cube = new Shape('Cube', 20, 20, 20);
// or
var cone = new Shape('Cone', 20, 30);
```

& that may do everything else for me, i can extract the `arguments` from the function but then what to do?
Say how to convert them from strings to logical statements?

Comment: Do you mean that the only thing that you'd have to change would be `THREE.BoxGeometry` to `THREE.ConeGeometry`?

Comment: Well i have to change other things as well but to  make it simpler i haven't mentioned them all in my code

Comment: I just wanted to get some idea for how can i change any one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bracket notation, you can make a function that accesses `Three.<word>Geometry`, while using rest syntax to collect the other arguments, and then spread them into the constructor:

```
function makeShape(shapeName, ...args) {
  var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  var boxGeometry = new THREE[shapeName + 'Geometry'](...args);
  var box = new THREE.Mesh( boxGeometry, material );
  box.position.set(-10, -10, 0);
  scene.add( box );
}
```

Then, just call that function:

```
makeShape('Cube', 20, 20, 20);
makeShape('Cone', 20, 30);
```

If you want to assign something created in the function to the caller of `makeShape`, just `return` it at the end.

Comment: I was just thinking about destructuring, thanks a lot.